# How do you localize the message of Ext.LoadMask?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, extjs

How do you localize the `msg` of `Ext.LoadMask`? I tried using `Ext.override`, but my gridpanel loading from a store still shows `Loading...` instead of the text I provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you don't have to override loadMask, you can set the text of the loading mask on the grid view. Just add the view config to your grid

```
viewConfig: {
    loadingText: 'your special text'
}
```

**Edit** 
You can override the grid view if you wan't the same text for all your grids

```
 Ext.override(Ext.grid.View,{
        loadingText: 'your special text'
    });
```

Comment: I have many grids, and I need to localize everywhere. How do I do this generically?

Comment: i understand... then you can override grid view, ill edit my answer

Comment: Ah, okay. I was trying to override viewConfig on the different panel classes, and that wasn't doing anything. :P. This works exactly as I need it to.